# 'FirebaseApplication' object has no attribute 'Authentication'

Tags: pi-3, python

I'm using the following code to fetch data from Firebase on Raspberry Pi but it shows following error. However I'm able to fetch data without authentication.

```
from firebase.firebase import FirebaseApplication
from firebase.firebase import FirebaseAuthentication
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/', 
authentication =None)
authentication = firebase.Authentication('secretkey', 
'prateekrai266@gmail.com', extra={'id': 123})
firebase.authentication = authentication
print (authentication.extra)
user = authentication.get_user()
print (user.firebase_auth_token)
result = firebase.get('/messages', None)
```

it shows following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/pi/code/dataauth.py", line 7, in authentication = firebase.Authentication('secretkey', 'prateekrai266@gmail.com', extra={'id': 123}) AttributeError: 'FirebaseApplication' object has no attribute 'Authentication'
```

I'm able to fetch data without authentication i.e. setting rules to true, by following code

```
from firebase.firebase import FirebaseApplication
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/', 
None)
result = firebase.get('/messages', None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a couple of mistakes that really confuse the Python interpreter, although it looks like you probably read [this documentation](http://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/), which contains completely broken code. I think it's unlikely that the code there has actually been tested before publishing, because there are a couple of mistakes:

1. You can't declare a variable with the same name as a module you import.

   ```
   firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/', authentication =None)
   ```

   That line redeclares the module `firebase` as a variable of type `FirebaseApplication`. In other words, you're stopping yourself from accessing what you tried to import later on, with the line `firebase.Authentication`
2. You're not importing the `firebase` module correctly if you did want to use the method above. You should instead *only* use `from firebase import firebase` if you intend to reference the classes as `firebase.FirebaseApplication` (and so on).

Take a look at the example given in the [`examples/` directory](https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase/blob/master/examples/firebase_example.py) of their repository. This shows the correct import method and usage.

Your code should look a little more like this:

```
from firebase.firebase import FirebaseApplication
from firebase.firebase import FirebaseAuthentication

app = FirebaseApplication('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/', authentication=None)
authentication = FirebaseAuthentication('secretkey', 'prateekrai266@gmail.com', extra={'id': 123})
app.authentication = authentication
print (authentication.extra)
user = authentication.get_user()
print (user.firebase_auth_token)
result = app.get('/messages', None)
```

Comment: @user72225 No problem. You might like to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) — on Stack Exchange, our way of saying 'thanks' is to accept an answer by clicking the 'tick' icon (which also gives you a +2 rep bonus!).

Comment: i did like your code but i cant authrize my acess . 'requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized' What i nee dto do in firebase ocnsole to permit email auth? i enabled it already on that